# Tags and Synonyms for Commandments Proposals?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

***Which tags, and tag-synonyms, should be used for categorizing questions regarding the examination of, and observance to:***

- Covenant Law, (Adam, Noahide, Abraham, Mosaic, and Messianic)
- Mosaic Law, (Statutes, Ordinances, Precepts, Commandments) - distinct from covenant.
- Jesus' Commandments, (Instructions, Judgments, Blessings, Curses, etc).
- Apostolic Commandments, (Instructions, Judgments, Blessings, Curses, etc).

I had suggested "NT-Commandments" for all New Testament related questions, but that tag has been removed from relevant questions.

**So - in anticipation of objections, here is the defense I presented earlier:**

The primary argument for appropriate tags for these questions, is: Isn't observance to these commandments THE primary reason for hermeneutics in the first place?  And if absent, isn't everything else irrelevant?

> **NASB, Ecclesiastes 12:13** - The conclusion, when all has been heard, is: fear God and keep His commandments, because this applies to every person.
>
> **NASB, Matthew 28:19-20** - Go therefore and make disciples ... 20 teaching them to observe all that I commanded you;

I can't imagine a valid claim for "proper hermeneutics" that does not support specific examination of "commandments" - which is THE definition for both being "Israeli", and a "Disciple of Christ".

***So, How can/should these questions be categorized?***

Answer (score 2):

Tags should roughly correspond to areas of expertise that one might specialize in. By your own argument, a `nt-commandments` tag would be contrary to that principle:

> Isn't observance to these commandments THE primary reason for hermeneutics in the first place?

If the observance of NT instruction is this fundamental to all hermeneutics, it isn't a meaningful subcategory.

Note that there might be a strain of theology to be followed there or even a related hermeneutical approach. But such a tag on this site does not add anything meaningful to the taxonomy. No experts are likely to be interested in or not interested in only those questions. Even if we did allow such a tag, the boundary of when *not* to use it would be so fuzzy as to render it meaningless.

**Conclusion:** I don't see a category here that needs splitting out into a tag or tags at all. Unlike something like [parables](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parables) or even [poetry](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) that defines a class of writing with unique hermeneutical principles that people might expect to find grouped, the assorted instructions across most of both testaments are not a clearly defined unique set of writings nor do they correspond to anything particular unique hermeneutically that would be of some specialty interest.

Comment: That is very much like saying, "Eating is the purpose of food, but it is pointless to have expert nutritionists". So, setting aside the logical fallacies in this answer, (red-herring, etc), and the obvious ontological need: Can you suggest an answer for the question? ***Do you have a recommendation for categorizing questions regarding observance to Biblical instructions? Should we just tag all of those questions under "law"?***  I am not asking this question to debate with anyone - which is what the answer is doing. As long as there is consensus to a solution - this debate is unnecessary.

Comment: @elikakohen Yes. My suggestion is _don't try to force a categorization on them at all._